# Playing a Frequency in OpenAL in C

Tags: c, audio, openal

I am trying to write a program to play a frequency for a time. I can't find any way of simply just playing a certain frequency. How do I go about doing this in OpenAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a video on properly reading form a WAV file ([huge credit to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V83Ja4FmrqE)) and how a WAV file is formatted ([explained here in detail](https://docs.rs/riff-wave/0.1.2/riff_wave/)) and did some trial-and-error work until I figured out how to do it. I figured that if I could make a WAV-style file with the frequencies in them and set up the OpenAL buffer and source manually, it would work.

I ran into some trouble when I found that the format differed from [the first explanation of WAV file format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) I found, as some apparently have [additional meta-data](https://docs.rs/riff-wave/0.1.2/riff_wave/#additional-meta-data), which I had to test for and skip over when trying to load a WAV file. Then I made a WAV file containing the frequencies and played it, which worked as well as I could have hoped for.

[Here's another article](http://tweakheadz.com/16-bit-vs-24-bit-audio/) about how bit-depth works that really helped me understand what I was doing.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who is trying to do something similar to this!